# Javascript is not following dropdown list choice

Tags: javascript, php

This case is about dynamic div's following the dropdown choice.
What you see works perfect if you must make a choice in the dropdown. This example is about a modify page where is already maked a choice in the past and the value is coming from the database.

The script:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accountics WHERE id = '$id'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>

<div class="col-sm-10">
  <select name="categorie" class="form-control" id="selectMe">
    <option selected value="<?php echo $row['categorie']; ?>"><?php echo $row['categorie']; ?></option>

 <?php                           
 $sql1 = "SELECT distinct naam FROM lijst_accountics_categorie";
 $res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) { 
 ?>                           

 <option value="<?php echo $row['naam']; ?>"><?php echo $row['naam']; ?></option>

 <?php 
 }

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM accountics WHERE id = '$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 

 ?>                               

  </select>
</div>
```

Now we have the script for the div's:

```
<!-- Category is restaurant -->
<div id="Restaurant" class="group">

   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="bedrag1_excl" class="form-control" id="field-1" value="<?php echo $row['bedrag1_excl']; ?>">
   </div>

</div>


<!-- If category is not Restaurant -->
<div id="Geen" class="group">

<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" name="bedrag_excl" class="form-control" id="field-1" value="<?php echo $row['bedrag_excl']; ?>">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Down here we have the javascript code for calling the div's following the dropdown. And here is something wrong, i think.
The value 'Geen' is everything what is not restaurant as a choice.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.group').hide();
   $('#Geen').show();

$('#selectMe').change(function () {
$('.group').hide();

var Restaurant = $("#selectMe").val();  

if(Restaurant === 'Restaurant') {
   $('#Restaurant').show();
} else {
   $('#Geen').show();
}   

})
});
</script>
```

If i refresh this page, the values are good implemented in the dropdown (values retrieved from the database values earlier saved).
Now you make a different choice from the dropdown and after that you must set it to the old value otherwise the javascript is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right solution. See below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.group').hide();

if($('#selectMe').val() === 'Restaurant') {
   $('#Restaurant').show();
}

else {
   $('#Geen').show();
}


$('#selectMe').change(function () {
   $('.group').hide();


if($('#selectMe').val() === 'Restaurant') {
   $('#Restaurant').show();
}

else {  
   $('#Geen').show();
}


  })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code loops in a `while`, look

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select name="categorie" class="form-control" id="selectMe">
```

Therefore, you have many instances `id="selectMe"`.
It's incorrect HTML. This is a logic error.
You need to use CSS classes instead of `id` for the `<select>`

And btw, if you are inside an event listener, you can just access the value by `$(this).val()`. It will address exactly the element that was changed.

Comment: Changing this gives me the same result. Is there something else i can try?

Comment: I need the <select> id for the javascript. How can i update the javascript then? I don't understand your answer.

Comment: I have changed the var in the javascript to: var Restaurant = $("#selectMe").val();